# Route middleware not working on live server

Tags: php, laravel

Ive run into a strange problem.
I have the following code in my laravel route:

```
Route::prefix("/user")->middleware("auth:api")->group(function(){
    Route::get("/",function(){
        return request()->user("api");
    });
    Route::post("/bank-transfer",[UserController::class,"mobileBankTransfer"]);
    Route::get("/bank-transfer/all",[UserController::class,"getAllBankTranfers"]);
});
```

The above works perfectly well when served from localhost on windows and consumed by an angular client. However , on a live ubuntu production server, it returns 500 unknown error.
This only occurs when consumed from the browser .
------------------EDIT-------------
i have found out the middeware doesent work at all even when placed on a single route, what is going on?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs and the logs inside `storage/logs` to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber, nothing helpful in either log i'm afraid

Comment: I'm not following, do you get error 500 on each request?

Comment: Only on requests that have the auth:api middleware. @SahandMoghadam

Comment: Can you put the application in debug mode and post the error?

Comment: It is in debug mode already. Yet i get a 500 *unknown error*. Which makes it particularly notorious

Comment: Would you please send an image from the error?

Comment: Go into your app/Exceptions/Handler.php, and add this to your `report` function: `\Log::error("{$e->getMessage()}  of type ".get_class($e)." on line {$e->getLine()} of {$e->getFile()}");`  See if it adds anything to your Laravel log when you try /cron again

Comment: @aynber, turns out the problem was that laravel didnt have write access to the storage folder. Ive fixed it now

Comment: Well, that would explain why there was nothing in the logs! Glad you found it